# MAIL_FROM Domain setup for relay-only useage

Tags: amazon-ses

I have Postfix setup on my VPS to relay all outgoing mail through AmazonSES and deal with all my incoming mail myself. I have recently setup DMARC and when analyzing my dmarc reports I find that everything passes except for my SPF Alignment. I'm a bit concerned that if I follow Amazons instructions to setup a MAIL_FROM domain that I will lose the ability to deal with my own incoming mail through Postfix, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, no, I don't lose the ability to deal with my own incoming email just by setting up a MAIL_FROM (sub) domain.